# Double list view onTouchListener doesn't dispatch event when an item on row is clicked

Tags: android, listview, touch-event, ontouchlistener, viewgroup

I am trying to dispatch touch event between listviews and I actually did it with this listener.

```
private OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    boolean dispatched = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.equals(listViewLeft) && !dispatched) {
            dispatched = true;
            listViewRight.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        } else if (v.equals(listViewRight) && !dispatched) {
            dispatched = true;
            listViewLeft.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
        dispatched = false;
        return false;
    }
};
```

I set this touch listener to both listViews. But when I also set another onClickListener to an item (ImageView) on a list row, the event is not dispatched to another. The list which contains the ImageView still scrolls but the other listView doesn't.

I've been looking for a solution for a long time. I tried [onIntercepttouchevent](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) but it didn't work either. Please give me a suggestion to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the OnClickListener is consuming your event and therefore it isn't reaching the list view behind it. A possible solution would be to use OnTouchListener on your ImageView instead and return false to make sure it isn't consuming the touch event.

Comment: OnClickListener only consumes the click at the first time. When i start to scroll (when swipe my finger on the imageview) the list is scrolled. But event is not dispatched to the second listview, so it is not scrolled. I also couldn't detect Click event with OnTouchListener. When I return false I can't get the MOVE or UP actions. So I can only use DOWN but it is not enough.